# Proyecto laravel no fucniona con Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Tengo configurados dos contenedores de Docker, uno para usar php 8.2 y otro para usar Mysql 8.0

Puedo conectarme al mysql sin problema, pero si quiero arrancar el servidor local para ver la web, no funciona, el navegador me dice:
Esta página no funciona127.0.0.1 no ha enviado ningún dato.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Si ejecuto  `docker-compose exec app-territory php /app/artisan serve` no da error:
   `INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].`

Pero el navegador no muestra nada, como si no estuviera arrancado.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes hacerlo asi `docker-compose exec app-territory php /app/artisan serve  --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

Comment: @Bryro lo he hecho así y da el mismo resultado. He añadido una imágen.

Comment: yo cree mi propio stack or lo mismo

Comment: Mira con `docker ps -a` para ver si tienes los docker arrancados correctamente. Añade el resultado de ese comando a tu pregunta, para tener más info al respecto